# How to output tilde with FORMAT in Lisp?

Tags: format, lisp, common-lisp

In Lisp FORMAT, all directives start with a tilde (~).
If I just want to output string "~", how can I do that with FORMAT?

Comment: The answer to this question is readily available via Google "lisp format", *e.g.,* http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered directly in the documentation on `format` directive [Tilde Tilde](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cae.htm).  (See this question on Meta: [What should one do if they have a question that the answer is already on google?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208372/225437))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
CL-USER 27 > (format t "~~")
~
NIL

CL-USER 28 > (format t "~10~")
~~~~~~~~~~
NIL
```

Comment: Documentation link: [22.3.1.5 Tilde Tilde: Tilde](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cae.htm).

Comment: Rainer explains it a lot better than the documentation.